# Phonegap plugin DatePicker not working in landscape mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using the PhoneGap plugin DatePicker (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/DatePicker). It works just fine in portrait mode, but I want to be able to use it in landscape mode as well.

If I first open the DatePicker controller while in portrait mode, it looks fine in landscape mode as well, but if I don't first open it in landscape, it is aligned to the right and looks broken. It's not possible to change year either. It seems the DatePicker is not updated every time it loads.

[image]

There is an 4 month old issue posted targeting this problem, but no one seems interested in taking care of this. (https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/issues/250) There is also a link to an article with a possible solution to this problem, but I don't understand Obj-C, so I can't fix this myself.

Could someone who understands Objective-C look at the code and help me with this issue? Or are there any other options? I really need to use this plugin in landscape mode!

Comment: Using html5 input=date instead, works fine in both portrait and landscape, but I think it's only iOS > 5, can someone confirm that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are right it is only for ios > 5 and secondly this plugin will aslo not work on iPad!